# Entity Framework Duplicate Record

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

Assume that I have this class:

```
public class Element
{
    [Key]
    public int ElementId { get; set; }

    public int? ParentId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentId")]
    public virtual Element Parent { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Element(string name, Element parent)
    {
        Name = name;
        Parent = parent;
    }
}
```

Now when I have

```
Element A = new Element("A", null);
Element B = new Element("B", A);
Element C = new Element("C", A);

Context.Elements.Add(A); 
Context.Elements.Add(B); 
Context.Elements.Add(C);
```

EF immediately writes three copies of A in the DB. How can I tell EF not to write the parent element unless it doesn't exist?

Comment: Are you setting their keys somewhere?  This doesn't look like EF code to me ... post more please?

Comment: entity should never have parameterized constructor.

Comment: @KingKing Perhaps "never" is a bit extreme, but it could be acceptable as long as you have a parameterless constructor too.

Comment: @DavidT.Macknet I don't set their key anywhere. EF automatically detects the key in the constructor. I am just testing EF and so I don't use the key anywhere.

Comment: @KingKing Why is it not a good idea to use parameterized constructor?

Comment: declaring a paramaterized constructor is useless when you can always use properties initializer. Also I think it's not very logical to declare parameterized constructor for an entity class. Remember that it is usually a map to some table/view in database, so just make it simple with parameterless constructor. It's some kind of pattern that should always work, while it's not sure for other way.

Comment: Without a parameterless constructor, EF can't create your entities, that's the main reason. So when you add one with parameters, you always need to ensure you add the parameterless version too.

Comment: Well, you say that "EF automatically detects the key..." yet I don't see anything in there to indicate that the key is assigned.  It looks to me like the `ElementID` never gets set, and that's what's defined as the key.

Comment: @DavidT.Macknet EF automatically assign an ID in this case by increment the number. No need to assign it any value.

Comment: However, because you do not assign a number, there's no way for EF to know that your item A is unique, nor that the relationships should be between the newly created items.  I just don't think EF will work that way, frankly.